# AMD radeon 8670m performance issues

Tags: laptop

I recently purhased a notebook with an Amd Radeon HD 8670m and a 8650g in crossfire, with 8gbs of ram. Seeing benchmarks online for dota 2 and cs go, i see dota should be running at around 54 fps on low settings, while i am getting 25 on low. I have enabled the dual graphics in the control center. Counter strike: go is also benchmarked at 132 fps on low, while i am getting around 35. The laptop is plugged in and everything is set to maximize performance while plugged in

http://www.notebookcheck.com/AMD-Radeon-HD-8650G-HD-8670M-Dual-Graphics.104345.0.html

Comment: What version of the video drivers do you have installed?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I have  the drivers that came with the laptop. I have tried using windows build in search the web for drivers function and it says everything is up to date.. How would i update it through amd catalyst?